# Advanced DataGridView DateTime Filter

Tags: vb.net, advanceddatagrid

In my win form application I have used 'Advanced DataGridView'. For filter string columns it is working good but when i filter Datetime column the grid view becomes empty.
When i did debug it, i came to known that it is getting only dates and not dateTime from the column i.e

```
([Date_Time] IN ('11/04/2017', '12/04/2017', '13/04/2017'))
```

and this is the reason why my grid view become empty because there is no row with only date.

here is my code for 'Change filterString' event

```
Me.crossMatchBindingSource.Filter = dgvCrossMatchDetails.FilterString
```

So, my question is how can i include time in the filter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please correct me if i m wrong. whoever created AdvancedDataGrid, the code he/she wrote to filter can only filter the date and not the datetime. So i should split my datetime in two columns then i will be able to filter my dates. Actually i have done it and it is working perfectly but time column shows every record separately like text in the filter and not making grope of hours and minutes as excel does.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to bind a grid view to a data source, which uses SQL to extract data from the databases.  I believe you can just amend your SQL as follows:

```
([Date_Time] between ('11/04/2017' and '14/04/2017'))
```

This should cater for times as well as dates.

Comment: I didn't write the query mentioned above so i can't change 'IN' to 'between'. This is the query that 'Advanced DataGridView' generates on run time when i filter a column like excel.

Comment: Your grid view will not work as expected then.  The query is looking for the following values: 11/04/2017 00:00:00, 12/04/2017 00:00:00 and 13/04/2017 00:00:00.

Comment: Then what is the solution to filter 'Advanced Datagridview" on DataTime column.

Answer (score 0):

You should just go to DataGridView properties and set "**DateWithTime**" to "**True**".
Then you are able to filter by Date and Time now.